# Can you fit a non-stationary model using the ar function in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit a simple AR(1) series with the `ar` function, but it gives bad results for non-stationary series.

I've tried to look up the `ar` function documentation and I did not find anything about it.

I simulate a series in the following way:

```
l = 100
alpha = 1.05 # first tried with 1.01, 1.02
x <- w <- rnorm(l)
for (t in 2:l) x[t] <- alpha * x[t-1] + w[t]
ar(x)
```

Instead of giving 1 as the variance, and the true alpha value, the alpha value never went above 1, and the variance was very off. The higher the alpha went the worse it got. For 1.05 the variance was around 600.

Comment: You can fit but the results become unreliable because of the Spurious Regression problem. Use the **AirPassengers** data which is coming inside the R with default `AP <- AirPassengers` then run `ar(AP)` . You can get the result.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term Spurious Regression problem, I'll read about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `ar` doesn't work, but I can give you a working solution for an ar(1): you could fit an exponential function using `nls`. Indeed, an autoregressive first order is a first order differential equation, which solution is an exponential:

```
library(nls2)
l = 100
alpha = 1.02 
w <- rnorm(l,0,1)
x <- vector(length = l)
x[1] = 5
for (t in 2:l) {
  x[t] <- alpha * x[t-1] + w[t]
}
data <- data.frame(time = 1:l,x = x)
fit <- nls2(x ~ c*exp((alpha-1)*time),
           start = data.frame(alpha = c(0.95,1.05) , c = c(-10,10)),
           algorithm = "random-search",
           data = data,
           maxiter  = 100)
summary(fit)


      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
alpha 1.023239   0.001427 716.942  < 2e-16 ***
c     2.649077   0.310785   8.524 1.91e-13 ***
```

This kind of approach can handle both `alpha` above 1 or under 1. Here I use `nls2` which allow to cover a range of initial values, which makes life easy when using non-linear fitting.

Comment: Are you sure it works like this? Can you provide proof / reference that you can just find the nls of the solution to the continuous differential equation and somehow deduce the alpha values for the discrete equation with noise? Also, isn't it cheating when I know that the model is AR(1)? the `ar` function does not assume that.

Comment: No I am not sure. I am just trying something because I though of it, and that it seems to work. ou are surely right that there are case where you can't use the continuous equation to deduce the discrete one.